# How to configure Nginx in docker and set server_names_hash_bucket_size

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-config

I added a server_name server_name `very.very.long.domain.name.used.in.this.example.org;` to my nginx default.conf and I got this error

```
nginx: [emerg] could not build server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64
```

I read the nginx docs and I said I have to add it in my http context

```
http {
    . . .
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    . . .
}
```

I created a nginx.conf under Nginx directory and copied it into /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}

http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    server_names_hash_max_size 512;

}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

But now nginx is not serving the default port 80

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name very.very.long.domain.name.used.in.this.example.org;;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://admin;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to the *Dockerfile* will change the value to 64 using `sed`:

```
RUN sed -i 's/.*server_names_hash_bucket_size.*/\t server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Add this line before starting `nginx`.

#### Explanation

The default *nginx.conf* has this line commented out, but displaying the default value of `server_names_hash_bucket_size`:

```
...
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 32;
...
```

This `sed` command will replace this line with a non-commented line which sets the value to *64* (set higher if needed):

```
...
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
...
```

This may be too late for you @ArthurDecker, but I hope it helps anyone else who has this

Comment: Didn't work for me, `nginx:latest` (currently `1.23.1`) doesn't have the `server_names_hash_bucket_size` commented, It's unset.